# Minimal polynomial of invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, invariant-subspace

Let $V$ be direct sum of its T-variant subspace $V_1,...,V_l$, and $C_T(x)=(x-e_1)^{m_1} \cdot\cdot\cdot (x-e_l)^{m_l}$ be characteristic polynomial of $T$. Assume $w(T-e_iI_n)^{m_i}=0$ for every $w \in V_i$.
I want to prove minimal polynomial $m_{T_i}$  of $T_i =T|V_i$ is the form of $(x-e_i)^{d_i}$with $1\leq d_i \leq m_i$.

Many textbook writes this is trivial but I don't see why. so I tired to prove this by setting $T=\begin{pmatrix}
T_i&O \\ C&D
\end{pmatrix}$. i.e., $$w(T-e_iI_n)^{m_i}=w\begin{pmatrix}
a_{m_i}T_i^{m_i}+...+a_1T_i+a_oI_n&O \\ C^*&D^*
\end{pmatrix}=0$$ for every $w\in V_i$, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: If you use the `pmatrix` environment you get automatically resizing parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $w(T - e_iI_n)^{m_i} = 0$ for all $w \in V_i$, the operator $(T - e_iI_n)^{m_i}$ is zero on $V_i$. Thus $T|_{V_i}$ satisfies the polynomial $(x - e_i)^{m_i}$. It follows that whatever the minimal polynomial of $T|_{V_i}$ is, it must be a divisor of $(x - e_i)^{m_i}$. Hence the minimal polynomial has the form $(x - e_i)^{d_i}$ for some $d_i \le m_i$.

Comment: what does it mean to be zero on $V_i$ in math formula?

Comment: @fbg An operator $A$ is zero on a vector space $V$ if $Av = 0$ for all $v \in V$.

Comment: then, why being zero on $V_i$ implies that result?

Comment: @fbg If $f(x) = \sum_n a_nx^n$ is a polynomial then $f(T)|_V = f(T|_{V})$. This is because by definition, for $v \in V$, we have $$f(T)|_Vv = f(T)v = \sum_n a_n T^n v = \sum_n a_n (T|_V)^n v = f(T|_V)v$$ Note that restricting to a subspace does not change how the operator acts, only on which vectors you are allowed to act on. So because $(T - e_iI_n)^{m_i}|_{V_i} = 0$, we can say that $(T|_{V_i} - e_iI_n)^{m_i} = 0$. Hence if $f(x) = (x - e_i)^{m_i}$ then $f(T|_{V_i}) = 0$.

Comment: thanks I got understood(except one thing..). my textbook uses row vector and I dont get why multiplication $w(T-e_iI_n)^{m_i}=0$ for every $w \in V_i$ implies $(T-e_iI_n)^{m_i}(w)=0$ for every $w \in V_i$..

Comment: @fbg If $A$ is a matrix with the entry $i,j$ not equal to zero then $Ae_j$ is the $j$-th column of $A$ is non-zero and $e_i^TA$ is the $i$-th row of $A$ and is non-zero. If you multiply by $0$ on the left or right and get $0$ for all matrices it has to be the zero matrix. (I am using $e_k$ for the column vector with a single $1$ in the $k$-th entry and zeroes elsewhere.)

Comment: I got it. Thanks for the answers!